# Proxy server do not request for account and password but using windows account to log on

Tags: windows-7, proxy, user-accounts, windows-authentication

I've setting my windows 7 system to connect a proxy server,settings tested in another machine which is all right.

But the proxy server does not ask for authentication info, 
no popup to ask for account and password.

It just use my current windows account to log that proxy server.

How can i configure the system to make it require account and password every time instead of using my windows account to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the proxy configuration to use some version of basic authentication method / digest. Currently most likely it is configured to use domain level authentication based on Kerberos or NTLM authentication. That is why it forces the Windows to use  your host username and password.